# Qt Function Duplicates Second Argument While skipping First

Tags: c++, qt

The following code is an excerpt from a Qt program of mine that takes multiple file names as input to several QLineEdits and, upon pressing a button, combines the files into one. I wrote the code originally in C++ as a command line tool and the problem arises now as I attempt to feed the input from the QLineEdits as const char* argv[] into the command line tool.

The problem is that, for some reason, the command line code takes argv[1] and argv[2] to be the second file while the Qt code assures me that argv[1] is the first and argv[2] is the second.

```
void VLay::condenseReflectanceFiles()
{
    /**makes argv for wo_condense**/
    const char* argv[size+1];

    /**initialize first entry which wo_condense, when ran in terminal, thinks is the executable**/
    argv[0] = NULL;

    /**converts the text in the LineEdits into character strings and adds to argv**/
    for(int k=0; k<size; k++)
    {
        argv[k+1] = fileList[k]->text().toUtf8();
        //cout<< argv[k+1];
    }

    /**add one for the initial executable entry**/
    wo_condense_R(size+1, argv);
}

int wo_condense_R(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout<< argv[1];
    cout<< argv[2];
    return 0;
}
```

Is there something theoretically wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following statement:

```
argv[k+1] = fileList[k]->text().toUtf8();
```

The `QByteArray()` returned by this expression:

```
fileList[k]->text().toUtf8()
```

is a temporary that gets destroyed at the end of the statement.  So the pointers that you are storing in the `argv[]` array are immediately invalid.

Maybe try something like:

```
argv[k+1] = qstrdup(fileList[k]->text().toUtf8().constData());
```

Be sure to call `delete []` on those pointers if you use `qstrdup()`.